# Не выводится нужная информация из базы данных Firebase в TextView

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-database

Я регистрирую пользователя, после чего вся введенная им информация записывается в базу данных Firebase. Человек при авторизации сразу попадает на страницу профиля, где ему должна выводится его имя и фамилия, но у меня не получается это реализовать, либо поле TextView остается с дефолтным текстом, который я ввел при создании TextView (делал через hint), либо это приводит к различным ошибкам. Ниже прикрепляю все свои классы.

Вот так выглядит БД

[image: Структура БД]

**Класс с регистрацией пользователя**

```
package com.example.finaljournalstudent;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class signup extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button back_main, register_reg;
    EditText email_str, first_name_str, last_name_str, middle_name_str, phone_str, password_str;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    DatabaseReference mRef;
    FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        findViewById(R.id.button_register).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button_back).setOnClickListener(this);
        email_str = findViewById(R.id.email_reg);
        first_name_str = findViewById(R.id.first_name_reg);
        last_name_str = findViewById(R.id.last_name_reg);
        middle_name_str = findViewById(R.id.middle_name_reg);
        phone_str = findViewById(R.id.password_reg);
        password_str = findViewById(R.id.password_reg);
    }

    private void registerUser() {
        String email = email_str.getText().toString().trim();
        final String first_name = first_name_str.getText().toString().trim();
        String last_name = last_name_str.getText().toString().trim();
        String middle_name = middle_name_str.getText().toString().trim();
        String phone = phone_str.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = password_str.getText().toString().trim();

        if (email.isEmpty()) {
            email_str.setError("Введите Email");
            email_str.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            email_str.setError("Введите корректный Email");
            email_str.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (first_name.isEmpty()) {
            first_name_str.setError("Введите Имя");
            first_name_str.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (last_name.isEmpty()) {
            last_name_str.setError("Введите Фамилию");
            last_name_str.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (middle_name.isEmpty()) {
            middle_name_str.setError("Введите Отчество");
            middle_name_str.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (phone.isEmpty()) {
            phone_str.setError("Введите Телефон");
            phone_str.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (password.isEmpty()) {
            password_str.setError("Введите Пароль");
            password_str.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (password.length() < 6) {
            password_str.setError("Пароль должен содержать более 6 символов");
            password_str.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    String email_s = email_str.getText().toString().trim();
                    String first_name_s = first_name_str.getText().toString();
                    String last_name_s = last_name_str.getText().toString().trim();
                    String middle_name_s = middle_name_str.getText().toString().trim();
                    String phone_s = phone_str.getText().toString().trim();
                    String password_s = password_str.getText().toString().trim();
                    String userid = user.getUid();
                    User users = new User(userid, email_s, first_name_s, last_name_s, middle_name_s, phone_s, password_s);
                    mRef.child(userid).setValue(users);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(signup.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Регистрация прошла успешно, теперь можете пройти авторизацию", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    if(task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Данный Email уже зарегистрирован", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_register:
                registerUser();
                break;
            case R.id.button_back:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Класс User**

```
package com.example.finaljournalstudent;

public class User {
    public String uid,email_c,first_name_c,last_name_c, middle_name_c, phone_c, password_c;
    public User(){}

    public User(String uid, String email_c, String first_name_c, String last_name_c, String middle_name_c, String phone_c, String password_c) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.email_c = email_c;
        this.first_name_c = first_name_c;
        this.last_name_c = last_name_c;
        this.middle_name_c = middle_name_c;
        this.phone_c = phone_c;
        this.password_c = password_c;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getEmail_c() {
        return email_c;
    }

    public void setEmail_c(String email_c) {
        this.email_c = email_c;
    }

    public String getFirst_name_c() {
        return first_name_c;
    }

    public void setFirst_name_c(String first_name_c) {
        this.first_name_c = first_name_c;
    }

    public String getLast_name_c() {
        return last_name_c;
    }

    public void setLast_name_c(String last_name_c) {
        this.last_name_c = last_name_c;
    }

    public String getMiddle_name_c() {
        return middle_name_c;
    }

    public void setMiddle_name_c(String middle_name_c) {
        this.middle_name_c = middle_name_c;
    }

    public String getPhone_c() {
        return phone_c;
    }

    public void setPhone_c(String phone_c) {
        this.phone_c = phone_c;
    }

    public String getPassword_c() {
        return password_c;
    }

    public void setPassword_c(String password_c) {
        this.password_c = password_c;
    }
}
```

**Класс страницы профиля**

```
package com.example.finaljournalstudent;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class studentpage extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView first_name_profile, last_name_profile;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    DatabaseReference mRef;
    FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_studentpage);
        first_name_profile = findViewById(R.id.profile);
        last_name_profile = findViewById(R.id.profile2);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
// Read from the database
        mRef.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.child("first_name_c").getValue(String.class); if(value == null) Log.e("AAAAAAAAAAAA", "value is null");
                else { Log.e("AAAAAAAAAAAA", value); first_name_profile.setText(value); }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_logout:
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Вы успешно вышли из аккаунта", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Activity профиля]

Именно на странице профиля и возникает проблема с выводом информации пользователя. Нужно чтобы для каждого авторизованного пользователя выводилась его информация. Где тут ошибка я не могу увидеть, так как в похожих работах я видел примерно эту же картину.  В документации firebase не получилось нормально разобраться, там описано для других ситуаций.

Comment: Приложите текст ошибки из LogCat, пожалуйста

Comment: На данный момент ошибки в LogCat нет, просто не выводится информация. То есть как был текст "Ваше имя" так и остался

Comment: Не могу разобраться в Вашем коде. У Вас одна активити приложена дважды с разным заголовком в тексте вопроса, это так и должно было быть?

Comment: Виноват, исправил

Comment: Добавьте `Log.e("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", value)` перед `first_name_profile.setText(value);` и посмотрите, выведет ли что-то в логи, пожалуйста (должно будет появиться сообщение вида ААААААААА что-то)

Comment: Выбило ошибку 2020-03-27 13:58:21.191 24231-24231/com.example.finaljournalstudent E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.finaljournalstudent, PID: 24231
    java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
        at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:263)
        at com.example.finaljournalstudent.studentpage$1.onDataChange(studentpage.java:42). Как раз на той строке которую вы мне прислали

Comment: хорошо, тогда добавьте проверку на `null` для `value`

Comment: Выводит такую же ошибку

Comment: А Вы проверку на `null` куда добавили? Выше, чем `Log`?

Comment: Попробовал и выше и ниже, выдает ошибку. А я могу как то отправить сам проект вам, чтобы уже более точно можно было понять в чем проблема?

Comment: firebase-то ключики просит) Да и я вряд ли стану столько времени тратить Проверяя на null что делали? А лучше - просто добавьте в вопрос проверку)

Comment: Я правда раньше этого никогда не делал, но над Log добавил это `if (value ==null)`

Comment: `String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                if(value == null) Log.e("AAAAAAAAAAAA", "value is null");
                else {
                    Log.e("AAAAAAAAAAAA", value);
                    first_name_profile.setText(value);
                }` я имел ввиду что-то такое

Comment: Вот что в LogCat пишет 2020-03-27 14:31:29.065 32186-32186/com.example.finaljournalstudent E/AAAAAAAAAAAA: value is null

Comment: Это значит, что `dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);` у Вас возвращает `null` вместо имени пользователя.

Comment: `mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child("first_name_c");` замените на `mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")` и `dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);` замените на `dataSnapshot.child("first_name_c").getValue(String.class);`

Comment: замените ее на `String value = dataSnapshot.child("first_name_c").getValue(String.class); if(value == null) Log.e("AAAAAAAAAAAA", "value is null");` И какой бы ни был результат - замените код в вопросе на текущий, пожалуйста

Comment: Изменил код, и вывелось имя Сергей! Навонец-то. Сейчас попробую по аналогии вывести фамилию

Comment: Хорошо, а я пока постараюсь в ответе расписать что и почему было)

Comment: Сделал по аналогии, всё отлично теперь работает, спасибо Вам огромное. 4 дня я убил на то, что оказывается решалось за 15 минут).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак изначальный код в вопросе выглядел так:

```
mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child("first_name_c");
// Read from the database
mRef.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class); 
        first_name_profile.setText(value); }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

Какие были ошибки:

1. Строку `mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child("first_name_c");` нужно было заменить на `mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");`. Нельзя получить имя, если еще не получен конкретный пользователь.
2. В `dataSnapshot` приходит не имя пользователя, а сам объект пользователя, а значит - имя еще надо получить. Заменяем `String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);` на `String value = dataSnapshot.child("first_name_c").getValue(String.class);`
3. Для удобства отладки имеет смысл сделать проверку хотя бы на `null`.

Применив все 3 рекомендации получим итоговый код:

```
mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
// Read from the database
mRef.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String userName = dataSnapshot.child("first_name_c").getValue(String.class);
        if(userName == null) Log.e("YOUR_LOG_TAG", "Error userName is null");
        else { 
            Log.e("YOUR_LOG_TAG", userName); 
            first_name_profile.setText(userName); 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```